# Nodemon command is not recognized since index.js moved

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I have an issue since I moved my "index.js" file out of the same location I have my 'package.json' for my server. Now, every time I want to run my server with the 'npm run dev' command, the following error appears on the console:

`nodemon is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

My code on my server's package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon index.js",
  "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && nodemon server.js",
  "prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && nodemon server.js"
}
```

My `index.js` file is on `server/index/index.js`, while my `package.json` is on my server's home directory. I tried to change my `start` command like this:

`"start": "nodemon ../index/index.js"`

but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused. Your question is about `npm start dev` but then you start talking about `index.js` but the `start` script is trying to run `server.js`. Anyway, it doesn't sound like `nodemon` is installed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install nodemon globally:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: I did it, and now my console is printing ```[nodemon] starting index.js``` over and over and over again every time I run my command.